# Plain text in Wordpress website looks bad running on mobile device

Tags: wordpress, text

Recently I built website on Wordpress.com but my first text looks bad in mobile device the address is [codecamp.kz](http://www.codecamp.kz). What is the problem?

[image]

```
<h1 style="text-align:center;">НАУЧИСЬ ПРОГРАММИРОВАТЬ НА iOS С НУЛЯ</h1>
<h3 class="r"></h3>
<div style="text-align:center;"><a class="button" href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfLVUls_4LAE-Gte_90wCHLwWulCS3N8aUix6mDZiw0XZFePQ/viewform">Подать заявку</a></div>
```

Comment: we need to see enough code to duplicate the problem, as well as what you've attempted so far. There's a helpful page on the topic here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: alexwc_ now code and screenshot have been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the browser detects your text as one word and browser interprets it shouldn't be broken.

You **don't need media queries** for this, instead you only need one css rule:

```
h1 {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

### Solution 2

For extra points! On your html you probably have something like:

`{НАУЧИСЬ&nbsp;ПРОГРАММИРОВАТЬ&nbsp;НА iOS С&nbsp;НУЛЯ}`

Just remove the `&nbsp;` and that should do the trick.

My example:
[image]

Hope this is useful.

**Edit** Added an image of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use media queries to size your text correctly. Also, that empty `<h3>` should probably be deleted. There are some odd `&nbsp` in the title - perhaps WordPress is putting those in?

Media queries will allow you to apply different styling based on different parameters: width, height, orientation, pixel density, etc... [Here are some helpful starter notes.](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/)

Here's an example of media queries:

```css
/* the following rules will only apply when the browser width is between the following widths. You can change the min/max widths to suit your needs. */
@media all and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width:1280px) {
  h1 {
    font-size:16px; /* or whatever size and unit */
    font-size:1.6rem; /* or whatever size and unit */
    }
}

/* OR */

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
 .element {
    font-size:26px; /* or whatever size and unit */
    font-size:2.6rem; /* or whatever size and unit */
 }
}
```

Also, [here are some media queries for standard devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Comment: alexwc_ I am new in WordPress where should I add this script?

Comment: @aatalyk I don't know wordpress.com (I only run self-hosted WP sites), but a quick Google showed [this page on adding custom CSS to wordpress.com sites](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-css/).